# View count of file in document library

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, document-library

I'm trying to use a Web content Display to show how many times a file in document library has been viewed

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is your file connected to your article?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I am providing high level points, as detail would be little long :

1. Create a structure and template, in template for your web content
2. In template, get the Document Library service and access the file using file id (you can either give the file id hard coded or take that from user using structure texbox elemnt
3. Once you get the DLFileEntry object, you can get the download count easily
4. Display that with fancy CSS!

Let me know if you need anything in more detail.